# How to find out what action and/or flag is used with imeOptions?

Tags: android, android-input-method

In the following code:

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    InputConnection  inputConnection  = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);

    // What is included in the outAttrs.imeOptions

    return inputConnection  ;
}
```

`outAttrs.imeOptions` is an integer value representing `EditorInfo` actions and flags.

How to detect which action/flag is used within `outAttrs.imeOptions`?

I tried to read the number but I found out it is a long number something like: `301216460`

I found that setting this value is done using `&` and `|`:

`outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT;`

Comment: `I tried to read the number but I found out it is a long number something like: 301216460` Can you provide how you did that?

Comment: @Ibrahim `imeOptions` is an integer! However, I did this way `Log.i(TAG, "imeOptions = " + imeOptions);` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to determine if an action or a flag is included in the `imeOptions` value.

To check if `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` is included in the `imeOptions` value:

```
if ((imeOptions & EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
// imeOptions includes EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
} else {
// imeOptions does not include EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
}
```

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to use a bitwise operator here. my brother

Comment: @Ibrahim Please, explain or refer me to why its not a good idea? And provide the other approach :)

Comment: `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT`  carrying `5` and your `imeOptions` is always carrying null value which is `0x00000000` by using `imeOptions & EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` It will always check for the `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` only.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to use bitwise operator here my brother, instead of that you can check on your input variable whatever is it, e.g:

```
if (editText.getImeOptions() == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
    //do it
else
    //not this time.
```

Comment: I see your point. However, my app is hybrid and I am using `CordovaWebView` and everything is HTML/JS/CSS. I do not have `EditText` I have `<input type="text" />`

Comment: @malhobayyeb I have no idea how it work with JS, but you may try `yourInput.getImeOptions()` and am sorry that I didn't help.